# How to display list of widgets in WordPress?

Tags: wordpress

How can I display all the list of widgets available in my website? I know I can use `the_widget('widget class name')` stuff from https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/the_widget/ and its working fine. 
 
But my problem is that I'm currently using avada theme and have this easily created widgets. I want to get the register_widget class name of the widget so that I can specify it on my template and apply it globally since I want it to display in all single post page.

Answer (score 0):

You can access the global [`$wp_widget_factory` instance](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/classes/wp_widget_factory/) that holds them.

```
<?php
foreach ( $GLOBALS['wp_widget_factory']->widgets as $widget ) {
    echo $widget->id_base."\n";
    echo $widget->name."\n\n";
}
```